# Replace a Picture in MS Word header with another in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using MS access I need to open a word document and change certain images within the header. Whilst I have the code to find and replace any text that I need, I do not quite understand how to replace an image keeping it to a specific width and height.

The header within the Word document is constructed using a basic table with 3 columns as depicted below. The image in the right hand column will need to change for a specific logo.

[image]

I have managed so far to add an image to the document using the following code which gives the expected result...

```
With WordDoc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory)
  .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="test.jpg"
End With
```

[image]

I understand that this is due to me not specifying a specific location, size etc but I am struggling to find resources which would instead allow me to either remove and add a new image to the right column or just swap the images out.

EDIT 1:

[image]

Comment: Need to specify cell to remove/insert image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WORD VBA Move image into a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920542/word-vba-move-image-into-a-table)

Comment: Okay so if I use the following {.Tables(1).Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="1.png"} then i can insert the image into the right place. However if i try to SET before this line with for example Dim thisPic As Word.InlineShape it shows with an error. How can I set this variable so that i can edit height & width?

Comment: Added an example to the OP

Comment: Code should be posted as formatted text, not image. Also include description of issue encountered, not scattered through comments. Sounds like the original question was resolved and you have another question.